# Jekyll not rendering code in the right way

Tags: html, markdown, jekyll

I have a blog that is based on [jekyll now](https://github.com/barryclark/jekyll-now).But the issue I face is that the it is very difficult for me to write code here.I have already tried using `<code>` and `~~~ruby` etc.None of them worked.This is the site for the [blog](http://anukin.github.io).And this is the specific one I am looking [at](http://anukin.github.io/change-the-horses/).This specifically is the [repository](https://github.com/anukin/anukin.github.io) where the blog is hosted.

Comment: Have you tried using backticks instead of tildes (```ruby)? I've never seen `~~~ruby` syntax before.

Comment: can you just tell me why it is downvoted? Those who were so easy to cast the stone must explain their disposition too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No magic in Jekyll. Just Read The F.. Documentation (RTFM). See http://jekyllrb.com/docs/templates/#code-snippet-highlighting

```
{% highlight ruby %}
def foo
  puts 'foo'
end
{% endhighlight %}
```

This just works.

Edit: be sure to leave a **new empty line before the opening tag**

```
<p>He had implemented ...<p>

{% highlight ruby %}
```

Comment: It does not work. I have tried all those methods under markdown, html etc.

Comment: A github repository can be useful to spot your problem.

Comment: I added one if you are aware

Comment: Nope even now its not rendering right.I just pushed the change

Comment: You have two space on the new line. Remove them.

Comment: but why did it happen anyway i had just two spaces.